# use one visualization with multiple filters

Tags: tableau-api

Let's say I have a visualization that is displaying production line output over time. There are 6 production lines and I only want to display one production line on the visualization at a time. I can add a Production Line filter to accommodate this.

I want to create a dashboard view for each production line. So I want to create 6 dashboard views each with the same visualization filtered for a different value. However, I do not know how to do this without creating a copy of the visualization and dictating the exact Production Line filter.

Reasons for doing this:

1. I want to publish the specific dashboards and be able to embed the view into a SharePoint site (that is Production Line specific) and not require the user to filter the view each time
2. If I make a change to visualization, I want it to be transferred to all dashboard views for all Production Lines and do not want to make the same change to 6 visualizations.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a dashboard. Try doing it with stories though. Create one story point for each production line. You can drop a single copy of your viz onto multiple story points, each with filters independent of each other, and any changes to the worksheet will be reflected in all six story points.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You could use a story as Sam M says, with 6 views of your dashboard each with a different filter setting,

Another choice that works in the embedded viz use case is to create a single dashboard, and apply a filter to all the worksheets on that dashboard. When using Tableau Server, you can supply the filter value as a query parameter in the URL (see the documentation)

After you test it out and are happy with the result, you can remove the filter control from the dashboard so it is no longer visible. You can still control the filter setting via the URL (or via the JavaScript API)

This allows you to adjust the viz that users see in your embedded view without making them manually select the filter setting, and also without creating six nearly identical dashboards.